# duplication of grouping header in Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

[image: Image of header duplication]I have a simple chat application. I am storing all the chat message in the Listview. I am grouping chats by their date on which they are sent. When It fetch for first time from database it shows the date for all chat message correctly but if we add new chat message to list the grouping header repeats for the new message of same date. I am using observable collection which is bind to Listview to store chat messages.

here is code for xaml

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="#2c7cb8" FontSize="14" 
                     Text="{Binding Name }" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListView.GroupStyle>
```

and code for .cs file

```
CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(
                       chatList.ItemsSource); 
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Date"));
```

Comment: try add `PropertyGroupDescription` in xaml

Comment: I tried that but it is not working for me.

Comment: Show what you tried then, personally I prefer xaml to do it

Comment: `<Grid.Resources>    <CollectionViewSource
        Source="{Binding Conversations}"
        x:Key="GroupedItems">
                <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                    <PropertyGroupDescription
                PropertyName="Date" />
                </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            </CollectionViewSource>
        </Grid.Resources>`   This is how Declare it on resources and use it   and bind it to listview.

Comment: what type is `Date` and how is its value assigned

Comment: date is a string property of collection and it comes from database which indicates the date of particular chat message

Comment: So i'm afraid this is the cause. the date can be very precise and when it is a string even a second of difference can result to anther group. can you upload a picture of the wrong result?

Comment: I have added image in question

Comment: it's very clear, the strings are different, and you can easily convert the `Date` to really `DateTime` type and only **Date** in precision

Comment: So how is wpf's listview grouped? It uses the == operator to determine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since from the comments I realized the OP is grouping by wrong data type, suggest following:

```
    //your existing code, I will not break it
    public string Date { get; }

    //change group by property to the following
    public DateTime RealDate
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(this.Date).Date;
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you were right, string type was the cause of the problem. Thank you for you help sir!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to enable live grouping:

```
ICollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(chatList.ItemsSource);
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Date"));

ICollectionViewLiveShaping liveView = view as ICollectionViewLiveShaping;
if(view != null)
{
    liveView.IsLiveGrouping = true;
    liveView.LiveGroupingProperties.Add("Date");
}
```

Alternatively you could refresh the view whenever you add a new item:

```
view.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the public declarations add a public bool:

```
/// Public Variable declarations

 public bool ViewSetSwitch = false;
```

then in your code at the line:

```
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Date"));
```

add:

```
// Checks if ViewSetSwitch is false and if so, runs the command
if (!ViewSetSwitch) view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Date"));

// set ViewSetSwitch to true so the command won't run again causing the headers to add again
ViewSetSwitch=true;
```

That's how I fixed this issue!